# Google map not showing on publishing page

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am going through a strange problem.

I am working on word-press theme and trying to display google map.
Initially map was not showing, i installed one of the well known plugins 
"API KEY for Google Maps by GeoDirectory" it helped me out to generate API key for map and then my map start displaying in page design view.

But when i published me page then map is not showing and on console the error is

> Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error

I googled and tried to read out multiple forums to get rid of this trouble and tried many suggested solutions but still going through this error.

Please help me out !

Thanks in advance !

Plugin.php

```
<?php
/**
 * This is the main GeoDirectory plugin file, here we declare and call the important stuff
 *
 * @package     GMAPIKEY
 * @copyright   2016 AyeCode Ltd
 * @license     GPL-2.0+
 * @since       1.0.0
 *
 * @wordpress-plugin
 * Plugin Name: API KEY for Google Maps
 * Plugin URI: http://wpgeodirectory.com/
 * Description: Adds API KEY to Google maps calls if they have been enqueue correctly.
 * Version: 1.1.0
 * Author: GeoDirectory
 * Author URI: https://wpgeodirectory.com
 * Text Domain: gmaps-api-key
 * Domain Path: /languages
 * Requires at least: 3.1
 * Tested up to: 4.7
 */

// If this file is called directly, abort.
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
    die;
}

/**
 * The current version number.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
define( "GMAPIKEY_VERSION", "1.1.0" );


add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'rgmk_load_textdomain' );
/**
 * Load plugin textdomain.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
function rgmk_load_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'gmaps-api-key', false, plugin_basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' );
}


add_filter( 'clean_url', 'rgmk_find_add_key', 99, 3 );
/**
 * Clean url.
 *
 * @since   1.0.0
 * @package GMAPIKEY
 *
 * @param string $url          Url.
 * @param string $original_url Original url.
 * @param string $_context     Context.
 *
 * @return string Modified url.
 */
function rgmk_find_add_key( $url, $original_url, $_context ) {
    $key = get_option( 'rgmk_google_map_api_key' );

    // If no key added no point in checking
    if ( ! $key ) {
        return $url;
    }

    if ( strstr( $url, "maps.google.com/maps/api/js" ) !== false || strstr( $url, "maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" ) !== false ) {// it's a Google maps url

        if ( strstr( $url, "key=" ) === false ) {// it needs a key
            $url = add_query_arg( 'key', $key, $url );
            $url = str_replace( "&#038;", "&amp;", $url ); // or $url = $original_url
        }

    }

    return $url;
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'rgmk_add_admin_menu' );

/**
 * Add the admin menu link.
 *
 * @since   1.0.0
 * @package GMAPIKEY
 */
function rgmk_add_admin_menu() {
    add_submenu_page( 'options-general.php', 'Google API KEY', 'Google API KEY', 'manage_options', 'gmaps-api-key', 'rgmk_add_admin_menu_html' );
}

/**
 * The html output for the settings page.
 *
 * @since   1.0.0
 * @since   1.1.0 Added button to generate API KEY from wp-admin.
 * @package GMAPIKEY
 */
function rgmk_add_admin_menu_html() {
    add_thickbox();
    $updated = false;
    if ( isset( $_POST['rgmk_google_map_api_key'] ) ) {
        $key     = esc_attr( $_POST['rgmk_google_map_api_key'] );
        $updated = update_option( 'rgmk_google_map_api_key', $key );
    }

    if ( $updated ) {
        echo '<div class="updated fade"><p><strong>' . __( 'Kay Updated!', 'gmaps-api-key' ) . '</strong></p></div>';

    }
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">

        <h2><?php _e( 'Retro Add Google Maps API KEY', 'gmaps-api-key' ); ?></h2>
        <p><?php _e( 'This plugin will attempt to add your Google API KEY to any Google Maps JS file that has properly been enqueued.', 'gmaps-api-key' ); ?></p>
        <p>

            <a href='https://console.developers.google.com/henhouse/?pb=["hh-1","maps_backend",null,[],"https://developers.google.com",null,["maps_backend","geocoding_backend","directions_backend","distance_matrix_backend","elevation_backend","places_backend"],null]&TB_iframe=true&width=600&height=400'
               class="thickbox button-primary"
               name="<?php _e( 'Generate API Key - ( MUST be logged in to your Google account )', 'gmaps-api-key' ); ?>">
                <?php _e( 'Generate API Key', 'gmaps-api-key' ); ?>
            </a>
            <?php echo sprintf( __( 'or %sclick here%s to Get a Google Maps API KEY', 'geodirectory' ), '<a target="_blank" href=\'https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_backend,geocoding_backend,directions_backend,distance_matrix_backend,elevation_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE&reusekey=true\'>', '</a>' ) ?>
        </p>

        <form method="post" action="options-general.php?page=gmaps-api-key">
            <label for="rgmk_google_map_api_key"><?php _e( 'Enter Google Maps API KEY', 'gmaps-api-key' ); ?></label>
            <input title="<?php _e( 'Add Google Maps API KEY', 'gmaps-api-key' ); ?>" type="text"
                   name="rgmk_google_map_api_key" id="rgmk_google_map_api_key"
                   placeholder="<?php _e( 'Enter your API KEY here', 'gmaps-api-key' ); ?>"
                   style="padding: 6px; width:50%; display: block;"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option( 'rgmk_google_map_api_key' ) ); ?>"/>

            <?php

            submit_button();

            ?>
        </form>

    </div><!-- /.wrap -->
    <?php
}

/**
 * Add special offer banner on settings page.
 *
 * @since   1.1.0
 * @package GMAPIKEY
 */
function rgmk_show_geodirectory_offer() {
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['page'] ) && $_REQUEST['page'] == 'gmaps-api-key' ) {

        if ( defined( 'GEODIRECTORY_VERSION' ) || get_option( 'geodirectory_db_version' ) ) {
            return;
        }
        ?>
        <div class="notice notice-info is-dismissible rgmk-offer-notice">
            <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/gd_banner.jpg'; ?>"/>
            <p><?php echo sprintf( __( 'API KEY for Google Maps was created for free by %sGeoDirecotry%s - The WordPress directory pluign. Discount Code: APIKEY25OFF', 'sample-text-domain' ), '<a target="_blank" href="https://wpgeodirectory.com/" >', '</a>' ); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'rgmk_show_geodirectory_offer' );
```

Comment: I set API key in plugin, where it supposed to be

Comment: @Ionut I didn't add this api key any php file because plugin does this for you .

Comment: Do you have a url where we can inspect the code?

Comment: @Gert-JanKooijmans

No, i'm using plugin in wordpress as i'm not much experienced with wordpress coding. That's why i have posted plugin code that's actually generating api key and responsible for showing map

Comment: @Gert-JanKooijmans

But yes, i can share with you any file like footer.php, header.php etc

Comment: Are you able to check your Database to see that the API key is there

Comment: @Bangsi

Where it should be in database ?